# Slightly confused on threading with Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm currently working with `Netty.io` to create an experimental project in which I nest multiple server instances(different listening ports) into a single application. However Netty pretty much takes over the thread that the `ChannelFuture` is bound to. `Blocks the thread` if you will.

Because of this, I've decided that I'm going to need to create a TPS setup, similar to that of a TPC(Thread per client), the application will use a thread for each server instance.

However there's a problem. The only time I've ever created a thread was when I needed to execute a runnable method; However now I'm trying to bind an entire instance of a class to the thread and I'm quite confused on how to go about it.

The only way that I know (Even after about two hours of research) to simulate this would be the following, but it just doesn't feel right.

```
public class Foo {

    public FooBar fooBar;
    private Foo() {
        System.out.println("Foo Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        new Thread(new Bar(this)).start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Foo();
    }
}

class Bar implements Runnable {

    Foo foo;
    public Bar(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        foo.fooBar = new FooBar();
    }
}

class FooBar {

    public FooBar() {
        System.out.println("FooBar Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }

}
```

The above code is executable, but is this the proper way to do it? It seems really hackish to me, but I don't have much experience with this.

Comment: Are you essentially asking how do you bind your JVM instance to a single thread? Because, down that road lays only misery. You are going to need to be very creative in how you design this project, because you can't just bind your JVM to a single thread and then spawn multiple threads all running the same thing out, it's just never going to work.

Comment: @James - I must have not worded the question very well; I'm trying to figure out how to use multiple threads for each instance. (For example, I have a class named `Foo` however I want every instance of `Foo` to run on it's own thread, but I'd like to have access to all of the instances of `Foo` from the "main thread". I understand that there are some concurrency issues that could arise here, but considering the "main thread" isn't for modifying that shouldn't be a problem. Each instance is complete independent of eachother, however the "main thread" will be used to monitor them via GUI

Comment: Ok, that's slightly more doable. Yes you can do this, and monitoring them from the main thread is something that is also possible. Investigate how to use JMX. This will let you monitor your objects at runtime.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out and open a question about JMX if I have any.

Answer (score -4):

As I understand it, this is a "how do I create a thread in Java question". Your example is an acceptable way to create a thread. One can also use an anonymous inner class for brevity:

```
(new Thread() { public void run() { /* enter code here */ }).start();
```

Comment: If you read the question more carefully, I don't think it's as simple as "how do I create a thread in Java". From OP's post, *"an experimental project in which I nest multiple server instances(different listening ports) into a single application"*

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes, OP goes on about his use case at length, but then fails to actually ask anything more than "how do I create a thread".